# Java swing applet freezes when button run

Tags: java, swing, applet

This is code I wrote for an applet using swing.  The program lets the user enter any extra items (peripherals), which shipping method they want to use, and then allows them to push buttons that calculate their total costs either with or without shipping depending on the button they push.
The problem is, when I run it, it freezes and doesn't do anything after I click either of the calculate buttons.  Does anyone see anything wrong with my code that could be causing this?
Thank you.

```
 package selling;


public class midtermComputers extends javax.swing.JApplet {
public double calculateCost(int quantity){

     double discountedPrice=getDiscountPercentage(quantity);
       double finalCost=0;
     if (isShipping()&(groundRadioButton.isSelected())&quantity<100){
     finalCost= ((discountedPrice*.05)+discountedPrice)*quantity;
     }
        if (isShipping()&(groundRadioButton.isSelected())&quantity>100){
     finalCost=discountedPrice*quantity;
     }     
         if (isShipping()&(airRadioButton.isSelected())){
     finalCost= discountedPrice*.1*quantity;
     }
         if (isShipping()&(fedExRadioButton.isSelected())){
     finalCost= discountedPrice*.2*quantity;
}
         if (!isShipping()){
     finalCost= discountedPrice*quantity;
 }
         return finalCost;
 }

private void calcWithShippingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
    int quantity=1;
    double finalCost=calculateCost(quantity);
outputTextPane.setText(outputTextPane.getText() + quantity + "\t" + finalCost  + "\n" );
     quantity=100;
 while(quantity<=1000){
outputTextPane.setText(outputTextPane.getText() + quantity + "\t" + finalCost  + "\n" );
quantity=quantity+100;
    }

    }                                                      

private void calcWithoutShippingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                          
   int quantity=1;
    double finalCost=calculateCost(quantity);
outputTextPane.setText(outputTextPane.getText() + quantity + "\t" + finalCost  + "\n" );
 quantity=100;
 while(quantity<=1000){
outputTextPane.setText(outputTextPane.getText() + quantity + "\t" + finalCost  + "\n" );
quantity=quantity+100;
}
}                                                         

public double calculateCost(){
double base=399.00;
double costOneUnit=0.0;
          double speakerPeripheral=0.0;
          double printerPeripheral=0.0;
          double scannerPeripheral=0.0;
          double microphonePeripheral=0.0;
          double projectorPeripheral=0.0;
          double plotterPeripheral=0.0;

while(speakerCheckBox.isSelected()){
   speakerPeripheral=89.00;
}

while(printerCheckBox.isSelected()){
  printerPeripheral=59.00;
}
 while(scannerCheckBox.isSelected()){
  scannerPeripheral=415.00;
 }
 while(microphoneCheckBox.isSelected()){
  microphonePeripheral=39.00;
 }
 while(projectorCheckBox.isSelected()){
  projectorPeripheral=549.00;
 }
 while(plotterCheckBox.isSelected()){
  plotterPeripheral=4883.00;
 }
 return costOneUnit=base+speakerPeripheral+printerPeripheral+scannerPeripheral+microphonePeripheral+projectorPeripheral+plotterPeripheral;

}


public boolean isShipping(){
if(calcWithShippingButton.isSelected()){
    return true;
} else{
    return false;
}
}

public double getDiscountPercentage(int quantity){
    double costOneUnit=calculateCost();
    double discountedPrice=0;

    while (quantity<100){
discountedPrice=costOneUnit;
}
    while (quantity>100&quantity<=199){
     discountedPrice=(costOneUnit-(costOneUnit*.01))*quantity;

}
    while (quantity>200&quantity<=299){
     discountedPrice=(costOneUnit-(costOneUnit*.02))*quantity;
}
    while (quantity>300&quantity<=399){
     discountedPrice=(costOneUnit-(costOneUnit*.03))*quantity;
}
    while (quantity>400&quantity<=499){
     discountedPrice=(costOneUnit-(costOneUnit*.04))*quantity;
}
    while (quantity>500&quantity<=599){
     discountedPrice=(costOneUnit-(costOneUnit*.05))*quantity;
}
    while (quantity>600&quantity<=699){
     discountedPrice=(costOneUnit-(costOneUnit*.06))*quantity;
}
    while (quantity>700&quantity<=799){
     discountedPrice=(costOneUnit-(costOneUnit*.07))*quantity;
}
    while (quantity>800&quantity<=899){
     discountedPrice=(costOneUnit-(costOneUnit*.08))*quantity;
}
    while (quantity>900&quantity<=999){
     discountedPrice=(costOneUnit-(costOneUnit*.09))*quantity;
}
    while(quantity<=1000&quantity>999){
      discountedPrice=(costOneUnit-(costOneUnit*.1))*quantity;  
    }
   return discountedPrice;
}
```

Comment: You have quite some `while` loops iterating on `quantity`. Inside these loops `quantity` never is modified, so the loops may be executed endlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "**while**" in calculateCost() should be "**if** "

```
public double calculateCost(){
       ...
       while(speakerCheckBox.isSelected()){
              speakerPeripheral=89.00;
       }

       while(printerCheckBox.isSelected()){
             printerPeripheral=59.00;
       }
       while(scannerCheckBox.isSelected()){
             scannerPeripheral=415.00;
       }
       ....
```

Like

```
if(speakerCheckBox.isSelected()){
      speakerPeripheral=89.00;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I made the changes, but I'm still having the same freezing issue when I click either button to make the calculations.

Comment: ALL your `while` statements need to be `if` statements, have a look at [The Event Dispatching Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for more details about why these are causing your issues

Comment: yes, look at all of your "while", like getDiscountPercentage() has the same issue.

Comment: Thank you.  Joe Lin already pointed out about my while statements but, even with those changes, I am having the same freezing issue.

Comment: Wait a second.. You guys are great!! Turns out, I missed replacing a couple "while", but when I got them replaced with "if", the program functioned! Thank you all SO much!